# How to set repeat interval time in background-tasks using django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, pyhook

I tried to run the background task code in Django. its working fine but interval time is not working. it working every second how to fix it anyone gives some solution.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from background_task import background
from django.core.mail import send_mail

@background(schedule=5)
def hello():
    print('hello_world')

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    hello()
    return HttpResponse('<h1> Hello World </h1>')
```

**I tried to pass repeat parameter also**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from background_task import background
from django.core.mail import send_mail

@background(schedule=5)
def hello():
    print('hello_world')

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    hello(repeat=10)
    return HttpResponse('<h1> Hello World </h1>')
```

I tried many ways. But still is not working.I need every One hour to print hello world.

Comment: Did setup a cron task to run these?

Comment: can please share some example code how to use cron task